# Trying to create a login with mongodb

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, authentication

I'm trying to check the details that the user enters in the login form matches in the mongodb data e.g.email and passsword.But this function is not working. When the user enters the correct information it should direct them to the homepage.

```
const logindetails = new Vue({
  el: '#logindetails',
  data: {
    errors: [],
    email: "",
    passwordInput: ""
  },

  methods: {
    login: function () {
      var account = db.collection('users')(userdetails.email === userdetails.email &&
        userdetails.passwordInput === userdetails.password) ? userdetails : null;
    });

if (account) {
  window.location.href = "welcomepage.html?email=" + account.email;
} else {
  alert("Email/Password has not been identified.");
     }
   }
  }
 });
```

Comment: Please explain why the function is not working. Is there an error? Does it fail to redirect the user? Also, please show what you have tried so far, this might save other people some work. Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It just says 'Email not identified'? I can't see an error in the console. The code I have written above it what I have tried so far.

Comment: Is this the entire code? Because your brackets and parentheses don't match. That could be what is causing the problem. If would help if you formatted your code correctly so you could see this more easily

Comment: Yes. This is the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to reformat your question to remove the HTML, I noticed that you have several unmatched parentheses.

You have an extra line `});` in your code that is blocking your `login` function from getting to the `if` statement.

Correct indentation can help you spot errors like this.

Here is the corrected code with the line removed.

```
const logindetails = new Vue({
  el: '#logindetails',
  data: {
    errors: [],
    email: "",
    passwordInput: ""
  },

  methods: {
    login: function () {
      var account = db.collection('users')(userdetails.email === userdetails.email &&
        userdetails.passwordInput === userdetails.password) ? userdetails : null;
      if (account) {
        window.location.href = "welcomepage.html?email=" + account.email;
      } else {
        alert("Email/Password has not been identified.");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the original code, with a comment beside the problem line

```
const logindetails = new Vue({
  el: '#logindetails',
  data: {
    errors: [],
    email: "",
    passwordInput: ""
  },

  methods: {
    login: function () {
      var account = db.collection('users')(userdetails.email === userdetails.email &&
        userdetails.passwordInput === userdetails.password) ? userdetails : null;
    });  //<-- looks wrong, stops 'login' function


if (account) {
  window.location.href = "welcomepage.html?email=" + account.email;
} else {
  alert("Email/Password has not been identified.");
}
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you for the help. I think there is an issue with the login function because I was trying to check if the details matched with the details in the mongodb. But it does'nt seem to be correct.

Comment: @JananiAshok recheck the answer above, I rewrote the answer so it may be more obvious. Your `login` function is not reaching the `if` statement. I hope I explained it well. Replacing your code with the fixed version at the top of my answer should fix your problem. Don't forget to upvote useful answers and accept any answer that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help but it's still not executing the if statement at all, I don't know where the issue is.

Comment: @JananiAshok load the debugger and put a breakpoint at the top of the `login` function. Check that it is executed. If it is, step through line by line to see where the problem is.

Comment: How can I do that if I'm testing it on chrome do I need to go on 'Sources'?

Comment: @JananiAshok Yes, go to "Sources", find your code, then press on the line numbers in the margin to set a breakpoint. Then when you try to log in, it will stop the code in your function. You can check the value of every variable after every line of code. It may be worth watching a tutorial on the subject

Comment: @JananiAshok you should post a new question about that and include more details. Good luck

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the help.